# Is it safe to privately inherit from a class with a non-virtual destructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor

I understand that with public inheritance it is in general *not* safe, since when `delete`ing a base class pointer the compiler only generates code to call base class's destructor, and the derived class's one is not called.

But for private inheritance the client can not cast a derived class pointer to a base class pointer (as private inheritance does not model *is-a* relationship), so `delete` is always used on derived class's pointer, and the compiler should be able to see that there is also a base class and to call its destructor.

I made this test:

```
#include <iostream>

struct BaseVirtual
{
    virtual ~BaseVirtual()
    {
        std::cout << "BaseVirtual's dtor" << '\n';
    }
};

struct BaseNonVirtual
{
    ~BaseNonVirtual()
    {
        std::cout << "BaseNonVirtual's dtor" << '\n';
    }
};

struct DerivedPrivVirtual: private BaseVirtual
{
    static void f()
    {
        BaseVirtual * p = new DerivedPrivVirtual;
        delete p;
    }

    ~DerivedPrivVirtual()
    {
        std::cout << "DerivedPrivVirtual's dtor" << '\n';
    }
};

struct DerivedPrivNonVirtual: private BaseNonVirtual
{
    static void f()
    {
        BaseNonVirtual * p = new DerivedPrivNonVirtual;
        delete p;
    }

    ~DerivedPrivNonVirtual()
    {
        std::cout << "DerivedPrivNonVirtual's dtor" << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "With explicit derived pointer type:" << '\n';
    {
        DerivedPrivVirtual * derivedPrivVirtual = new DerivedPrivVirtual;
        DerivedPrivNonVirtual * derivedPrivNonVirtual = new DerivedPrivNonVirtual;

        delete derivedPrivVirtual;
        delete derivedPrivNonVirtual;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "With base pointer type:" << '\n';
    {
        // Client code can't cast Derived to Base when inherit privately.
        //BaseVirtual * derivedPrivVirtual = new DerivedPrivVirtual;
        //BaseNonVirtual * derivedPrivNonVirtual = new DerivedPrivNonVirtual;

        //delete derivedPrivVirtual;
        //delete derivedPrivNonVirtual;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "Inside derived class itself:" << '\n';
    {
        DerivedPrivVirtual::f();
        DerivedPrivNonVirtual::f();
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "With non-dynamic variables:" << '\n';
    {
        DerivedPrivVirtual derivedPrivVirtual;
        DerivedPrivNonVirtual derivedPrivNonVirtual;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Both GCC 4.7.1 and CLang 3.1 give the same output. The derived class constructor is called except when the derived class itself casts a derived class pointer to base class and `delete`s it.

Besides this case which seems quite uncommon and easily avoidable (class's author is the only guy who can do harm, but it does know from which class it derived its one), can I conclude that it is safe?

```
With explicit derived pointer type:
DerivedPrivVirtual's dtor
BaseVirtual's dtor
DerivedPrivNonVirtual's dtor
BaseNonVirtual's dtor

With base pointer type:

Inside derived class itself:
DerivedPrivVirtual's dtor
BaseVirtual's dtor
BaseNonVirtual's dtor  <-- Only a problem inside the class itself

With non-dynamic variables:
DerivedPrivNonVirtual's dtor
BaseNonVirtual's dtor
DerivedPrivVirtual's dtor
BaseVirtual's dtor
```

---

Bonus question: what about protected inheritance? I suppose that the ability to do harm is no longer prerogative to directly derived class's author, but to authors of any class in the hierarchy.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Scott Meyers (author of Effective C++, More Effective C++) still doesn't even know what protected inheritance means. Public is an "is-a" relation-ship, Private is "implemented-in-terms-of", but Protected? That's kind of scary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whether inheritance is public or private does not affect the safety of the code, it just limits the scope in which it can be used safely/unsafely. You have the same basic issue: if your class or a friend of your class passes an object of your type to an interface that takes a pointer to the base without virtual destructor, and if that interface acquires ownership of your object then you are creating undefined behavior.

The problem in the design is that as per your question, the `BaseNonVirtual` is not designed to be extended. If it was, it should have either a public virtual destructor, or a protected non-virtual one, ensuring that no code will be able to call delete on a derived object through a pointer to the base.

Comment: Any construct can be misused. Is it safe to declare a private data member? Oh noes, you can accidentally set it where not aporopriate! "Safe" normally means "not open to abuse by others" and private inheritance is as safe as a private data member.

Comment: @n.m.: If you carefully read the first paragraph you should note that it mentions the cases under which this construct will fail: *if your class [..] passes an object of your type to...*. It also mentions what the solution to this hole is in the second paragraph. Private inheritance is as safe as a private data member as long as you don't yield pointers to members away, but that is uncommon. On the other hand, inheritance is often used to give pointers to the base --if inheritance is (ab)used to obtain the functionality that is a different design issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a case where client code *can* cast Derived to Base despite private inheritance:

`delete reinterpret_cast<BaseNonVirtual*>(new DerivedPrivNonVirtual);`

Thus skipping execution of `~DerivedPrivNonVirtual()`.

But, given how much the use of `reinterpret_cast` is discouraged, you may conclude that it's "safe enough" for your purposes.